# Why is the Bellman-Ford's shortest path algorithm sometimes called Bellman-Kalaba?

Tags: history

I see here and there, mostly in operations research courses in France that the Bellman-Ford algorithm related to shortest paths is called the Bellman-Kalaba algorithm. Could you explain the reason why it is called like that?

I searched and found a scientist named Roger Kalaba who seems to have been working with Bellman a lot. Why don't we call the Bellman-Ford-Kalaba algorithm? Is Bellman-Ford more spread than Bellman-Kalaba because Ford's contribution is bigger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting historical question. In Section 8.7, Chapter 8 of [*Algorithms* (2019)](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/Algorithms-JeffE.pdf)<sup>1</sup>, Erickson notes that

> The simplest implementation of Ford’s generic shortest-path algorithm was
> first sketched by Alfonso Shimbel in 1954, described in more detail by Edward
> Moore in 1957, and independently rediscovered by Max Woodbury and George
> Dantzig in 1957, by Richard Bellman in 1958, and by George Minty in 1958.
> (Neither Woodbury and Dantzig nor Minty published their algorithms.) In full
> compliance with Stigler’s Law, the algorithm is almost universally known as
> Bellman-Ford, because Bellman explicitly used Ford’s 1956 formulation of relaxing edges, although some authors refer to "Bellman-Kalaba" and a few early sources refer to "Bellman-Shimbel".

In particular, the name Bellman-Kalaba is occasionally used for the following reason:

> This name is most likely a reference to Richard Bellman and Robert Kalaba’s monograph on dynamic programming and control theory<sup>[2](https://www.elsevier.com/books/dynamic-programming-and-modern-control-theory/bellman/978-0-08-091653-8)</sup>, which describes Bellman’s algorithm. Bellman and Kalaba also published an extension of Bellman’s algorithm in  that computes $k$th shortest paths, for any constant $k$.<sup>[3](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0108044?journalCode=smjmap.1)</sup>

<sub>References</sub>

<sub>[1] Erickson, J. (2019). *Algorithms.* University of Illinois Press.</sub>

<sub>[2] Bellman, R., Kalaba, R. E. (1965). *Dynamic programming and modern control theory* (Vol. 81). New York: Academic Press.</sub>

<sub>[3] Bellman, R., Kalaba, R. (1960). On $k$th best policies. *Journal of the Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics.* 8(4):582-588.</sub>